# Angular JS (For Loop) Timer

Tags: angularjs

I have an array.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
  console.log(a);
};
```

What do I need to do in order to create a timeout for this loop? Lets say I want to delay by 1 second.

Reason is because I want to http get() from a website and I don't want to flood them, however I want to make sure I get a response back prior to issuing my next response. However if a response comes back faster than 1 second I want to wait at least one second.

I have tried $interval, sometimes I get a response back from the server in 4 seconds and it issues more prior to the response coming back.

I am guessing I need promise prior to firing the next event? but a timer as well?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $q.serial (a function not included by default in AngularJS) that is implemented and explained [here](http://www.codeducky.org/q-serial/).

```
var createTask = function (i) {
  return function (delay) {
    var start, end, nextRequestNeedsDelay;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (delay) {
      $timeout(function() {
        start = Date.now(); 
        $http.get("/foo")
          .then(function () {
            console.log(i);
            end = Date.now();
            nextRequestNeedsDelay = end - start < 1000;
            deferred.resolve(nextRequestNeedsDelay);
          });
      }, 1);
    } else {
        start = Date.now(); 
        $http.get("/foo")
          .then(function () {
            console.log(i);
            end = Date.now();
            nextRequestNeedsDelay = end - start < 1000;
            deferred.resolve(nextRequestNeedsDelay);
          });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  };
};

var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var tasks = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
  tasks.push(createTask(i));
};

$q.serial(tasks);
```

Answer (score 1):

*You can use the Promise Concept of angular. Promise provide the synchronous facility.*

I demonstrate you to by giving the demo example

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[ ]);

app.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$q,$timeout){

var task1 = $q.defer();
task1.promice.then(function(value){
       // write a code here for your task 1 success
} ,function(value){
       // write a code here for your task 1 error
});

var task2 = $q.defer();
task2.promice.then(function(value){
      // write a code here for your task 2 success
} ,function(value){
     // write a code here for your task 2 error
});

$q.all([task1.prpmice,task2.promice])
     .then(function(){
             // write a code which is executed when both the task are completed
    } ,function(){
            // write a code which is executed when some of the task are rejected
});
}
```

The above code will help you to understand the promice concept of angular

Comment: I understand i have to use a promise. But my question is how to use a timeout with with a for loop.

Comment: Ok dear, Let me check